# Dynamically change the size of a container view in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

As the title suggest, I am trying to change the size of a container view that resides within a table view controller. The following code calculates the height that the container view will have to become.

Basically it will take the height of the users phone subtracted by the last cell's Y-AXIS in the table view.

I have attempted to use `containerView.bounds.maxY` and set its value, however xcode gives me an error saying that it is only a get property. So i was wondering how someone would go about doing this? There has to be a function I can override before the container view gets displayed with my custom calculated height.

```
var dynamicCotainerViewHeight: CGFloat?
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // call somesort of method that will be called before the container view gets displayed
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if cell.reuseIdentifier == "lastStaticCell" {
            let rectOfCellInTableView = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
            let rectOfCellInSuperview = tableView.convert(rectOfCellInTableView, to: tableView.superview)

            let screenheight = self.view.frame.size.height

            // Get the desired height for the container view
            dynamicCotainerViewHeight = CGFloat(screenheight) - CGFloat(rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y)
            print("Height of dynamic\(dynamicallyAllocatedCellHeight)")
        }
    }
```

This is what I have so far in the storyboard to give a better understanding of what I mean. Since I cannot seem to constrain the container view to its superviews bounds I am stuck with this problem

[image]

Comment: What problem are you facing .? Can you post screenshot. ?

Comment: Why is setting `containerView.frame.height` not an option?

Comment: Your container view is the table footer view. Move it out of the table view (e.g. drag it between Exit and First Responder) and change the referencing type from weak to "strong" (delete `weak`) from your source code. Write a method like this: 1) tableView.reloadData(), 2) Get the tableView.contentSize 3) Use view.frame.size.height - tableView.contentSize.height for the height of the container view. 4) Set the tableFooterView  of table view to the container view.

Comment: the .height property is a get only property thats why I cant assign it. Also bubuxu, I cant seem to drag it between exit and first responder. Only below first responder. And when I do that, the entire container view in storyboard gets shifted out from the "frame of the display"

Comment: Yes, that's what I want you to do it. "Shift it out" so it's not the table's footer view anymore - you will assign it back later in code. the **containerView.frame.size.height** is not readonly property, but the _containerView.frame.height_ is. Check your code to make sure you are using frame.size.height rather than frame.height.

Comment: One more thing - don't write code in tableView:willDisplay:forRowAt: if you are not changing the color of the cell or subviews: This method gives the delegate a chance to override **state-based** properties set earlier by the table view, such as **selection and background color**. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and **frame** properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.